# When is a user no longer considered a new user?

Tags: discussion, new-users, rate-limiting

I tried asking two questions on MSO within 10 minutes of each other, and was blocked from posting the 2nd one until 20 minutes pass.

1. What are the criteria for no longer being a new user?
2. Should users who are new to *one* of the SO sites, but are no longer new in one of the others still be considered new for the purposes of limiting questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set out [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/), with summary:

> **If you’re a new user, with reputation below 100**
>
> - You may only post 1 question every 20 minutes
> - You may only post 1 answer every 3 minutes

and then Jeff added (in the comments):

> if your rep is > 100 you are totally immune to this rate limiter.

The 20 minutes surprises me, unless they've had to revise the numbers. But it won't be long before you have 100+ points. And register your account too; that may help (and it'll avoid you losing it when your browser dumps the cookies).

Comment: With regard to part #2 of the question, I'd like to point out that the association bonus is 100 rep, which brings an experienced user joining a new site immediately up to 101 rep and thus immune to the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are timing limits all over the StackOverflow-like sites to prevent abuse, spamming, and automatic attacks.

I don't know if the 20-minute-per-question limit is specific to "new users" but don't feel slighted. Those types of reasonable-use limits are imposed all over the system, even for "veterans."