# Who is considered to be a new user for review queues?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, late-answers

There are review queues for posts from new users (First Posts & Late Answers). Who is considered to be a new user for these queues? [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1270/223202) mentions new users as those below 100 reputation but it's in relation to post rate limit. Perhaps I'm looking wrong but I haven't found the definition for the queues.

Who is a new user for the review queue? Is it the same as for the post rate limit, i.e. <100 reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177553/1288) by Shog9:

> Answers posted at least 30 days after the question was asked (when posted by [a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user)) are considered "late" for the purpose of that queue.

Since he links to the new user privileges page, it looks like a new user is defined as anyone with less then 10 reputation for the purposes of the review queues.

---

I could be wrong, but I'd imagine that reputation could be ignored completely for the "first post" review queue.  The only reason I can see to include it is if we want to skip reviewing first posts by people who have the reputation association bonus after coming from another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thanks, 10 reputation definitely makes more sense then 100.
And just to clarify - first posts mean really first posts, not all posts from new users, right?

Comment: Correct, @Mifeet.

Comment: I submitted a request to broaden the First Post qualifiers here: ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171512/broaden-the-qualifications-for-a-first-post-or-a-late-answer ) I think expanding the range would help catch more problems.